# How to connect IntelliJ IDEA to my GIT repo?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

A weird thing happened. I opened my project in IntelliJ, and the IDE seemed to have access to all the GIT branches although I have not set up the SSH keys to the project and it was the first time it connects to the IDE.
Next thing I try to push up into remote, and get the following error:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've already tried setting "SSH executable" --> Native
yet the problem persists.

Please help me connect with remote, and finally get this merge request conflict resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IDE seemed to have access to all the GIT branches

Git is a DVCS, the repository is local, so some information about branches is available without access to remote.

> I have not set up the SSH keys

Are the keys setup already? Does git pull/push work on the command line?
Make sure git on the command line (cmd.exe if you are on Windows, do not test in GitBash)

> I've already tried setting "SSH executable" --> Native

Seems you are using an old IDE version, consider updating to 2018.3 or 2019.1, as only starting from 2018.3 IntelliJ can handle password/passphrase prompts from Native SSH.